# Is it necessary to create users and database instances sequentially while using Infrastructure as Code?

Tags: sql, deployment, terraform, google-deployment-manager, infrastructure-as-code

I was seeing this Deployment Manager template on Google Foundation Toolkit on Github

I am not able to get it what this line is for.
[Github Repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-foundation-toolkit/blob/f92f86d88494ac8dacdbafdca84803be4415afbc/dm/templates/cloud_sql/cloud_sql.py#L242)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a reference to another function within the template ([line 184](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-foundation-toolkit/blob/f92f86d88494ac8dacdbafdca84803be4415afbc/dm/templates/cloud_sql/cloud_sql.py#L184)). The reason this does it sequentially is that the [API call to add a user](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/rest/v1beta4/users#User) to the DB only handles adding a single user at a time. The act of adding a user to CloudSQL through API cannot be done in a batch. Since DM creates all these resources through API call, the sequential calls are required